# Google-NearBy video stream client's SurfaceView blank

Tags: android, google-nearby

Hello I'm trying to stream video from camera by Google NearBy Connections.
the connection established and messaging works but when I send stream the server device surface view show the camera preview but the client receive nothing with no error this is how is stream:
server:

```
SurfaceView surface;
public void sendCam(){
    try {
        surface = findViewById(R.id.surface);
        ParcelFileDescriptor[] payloadPipe = ParcelFileDescriptor.createPipe();

        ParcelFileDescriptor readFD = payloadPipe[0];
        ParcelFileDescriptor writeFD = payloadPipe[1];

        mCamera = Camera.open();
        MediaRecorder rec = new MediaRecorder();

        mCamera.lock();
        mCamera.unlock();

        rec.setCamera(mCamera);
        rec.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);    
        rec.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);  
        rec.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);

        rec.setPreviewDisplay(surface.getHolder().getSurface());

        rec.setOutputFile(writeFD.getFileDescriptor());
        send(Payload.fromStream(readFD));

        rec.prepare();
        rec.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

client receive:

```
    @Override
    protected void onReceive(Endpoint endpoint, Payload payload) {
    if (payload.getType() == Payload.Type.STREAM) {
            try {
                MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
//              mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(payload.asStream().asParcelFileDescriptor().getFileDescriptor()); // did  not work also
                FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(payload.asStream().asParcelFileDescriptor().getFileDescriptor());
                mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(inputStream.getFD());
                mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(surface.getHolder());
                mMediaPlayer.prepare();
                mMediaPlayer.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm not even sure if i can stream video using nearby, the sample projects show how to stream audio. is this api not able to stream video or there is a problem with my code and what it could be.

UPDATE:

} catch (IOException e) { GIVES ME setDataSource failed.: status=0x80000000

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in Nearby Connections that precludes you from sending video streams -- if yours is a 1:1 scenario (one client device connected to one server device), it would be better to use the [P2P_STAR Strategy](https://developers.google.com/nearby/connections/strategies#p2p_star) (if you aren't already) since it provides you a higher bandwidth connection (which should help with video).

To make sure that you're at least receiving the stream's raw bytes on the client, you can check whether the [onPayloadTransferUpdate() callback](https://developers.google.com/nearby/connections/android/exchange-data#progress_updates) is firing.

If not, then you should check that same callback on the server, to see whether or not the bytes are being sent out.

If no bytes are being sent out from the server, then it might be a problem with your application-level video capture code.

Good luck!

Comment: Yes I'm using P2P_STAR, and will check onPayloadTransferUpdate( by a toast? so no need for more code like buffering or write to a temp file?

Comment: Yes the payload transfered and upated like every second or less, the server surface display the camera preview but client surface remains black

Comment: catch (IOException e)  GIVES ME setDataSource failed.: status=0x80000000

Comment: MediaPlayer requires the InputStream to be seakable (eg. FileInputStream), and does not allow an InputStream of unknown size to be played.

Comment: I did this as you see under the commented line what else

Comment: The fact that it's streaming from another device means it has an unknown size. You won't be able to use MediaPlayer, unfortunately. I don't really have a good, simple solution I can give you. Video streaming is definitely more trouble than it should be.